# Mouseover doesn't work after margin-left transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website for a computer company I am starting and for some reason after the `margin-left` transition goes to make room for the specs to fade in, the black case is the only one which has a working mouseover. The mouseover for the silver and red case stops working until you click on the X to close the specs.

The website is http://angryrhinocomputers.com

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: And now I see that the black case doesn't fade, it just disappears and reappears.

Comment: hi...welcome to SO....to get a good answer....please post your html/css/javascript which you have tried...

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm really confused since the mouseover doesn't work to change the case selection on the color selector either.

I'm having an epic brain fart right now.

Comment: Damien, Hovering over a case will make the others fade out, as well as hovering over the color on the color panel below the cases. After clicking on specs, the hovering only works with 1 of the cases, instead of all 3 like it did before clicking specs.

Comment: Oh Ok - Sorry I understand what you are saying now. The only way I can get the condition you describe to occur is by clicking on the word "specs"... Wouldn't it be more intuitive to make the specs panel on the top right appear when you click on the relevant case? Also this isn't really friendly for mobile devices that don't really process mouse over functions properly.

Comment: wait...you want that, when user hover on the `color-palette`, the corresponding image should be visible,rest should fade off???

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem. It only screws up when you click specs. I need it to work as it does before clicking specs, after clicking specs.

I will be making a watered down mobile version after I finish the regular site.

Comment: NoobEditor: Yes, and it works perfect, until you click on the specs button. When you click on the specs button, and it transitions the cases to the left to make room for the specs, for some reason only the black case can be selected.

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly. Anyway, you have some errors to sort out: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null >> document.getElementById("umx2-black-faded").id = "umx2-black-faded-specs";

Comment: Damien, I'm really bad at explaining things sometimes. It just needs to work how it does when you first visit the page, after you click specs. Also, I now see all those errors in the JS looking in chrome, but it just says the id is null which it is not, and they all have valid css references. I'm not sure I understand what to do about that now either o.O

Answer (score 0):

Hy, first you should really consider using classes for css changes not the id.

Try to leave the id as it is and give your div classes that change on mouseover/mouseout.

But if you want to continue this way you should check this out:

When you try for example to fade-in the silver case and fade-out the rest you use this function:

```
function selectSilver(){
    document.getElementById("umx2-black").id = "umx2-black-faded";
    document.getElementById("umx2-red").id = "umx2-red-faded";
    document.getElementById("c-silver").id = "c-silver-mo";
    document.getElementById("colors").id = "colors-mo";
}
```

But at this moment the `"umx2-black"` div has is fact the id: `"umx2-black-specs"`

That is why I recommend using classes, because you can add multiple classes to one element.

...

So to be more clear:

- When you open the specs you change the id of the black case to "umx2-black-specs";
- When you hover over the rest of the cases you try to change the id of the black case from "umx2-black" to "umx2-black-faded"

  The problem is that you are looking for "umx2-black" not "umx2-black-specs" that is why you get an error in the above function.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, however, is that the cause for the red and silver cases mouseover's not working after the specs div has appeared? I don't get what makes the mouseover's stop working on those cases and color selector for those cases when the specs open.